# Eclipse breakpoint filtering restriction to location unavailable

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 4.7.0 and 4.7.1a respectively for different projects on two different machines. In 4.7.0, under Breakpoint Properties... > Filtering, I can restrict the breakpoint to a thread or to locations (classes and packages). In 4.7.1a, the dialog only shows the thread selection, i.e. I cannot restrict to locations. Is this a bug in 4.7.1a or a config issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Restrict to Selected Location(s)*** filtering is only available **for Java exception breakpoints**, not for example for line or for method breakpoints.

Filtering based on the location would make no sense for breakpoints like line or method breakpoints that reference code at a specific location.

This applies to both Eclipse 4.7.0 and 4.7.1a:

1. Create an exception breakpoint via ***Run > Add Java Exception Breakpoint...***
2. Right-click the breakpoint and choose ***Breakpoint Properties...***
3. In the *Breakpoint Properties* dialog switch to ***Filtering***

Comment: Of course, now that you say it. I was subconsciously hoping for a way to restrict a method breakpoint based on the class of the caller...

Comment: @warakawa You can add a Trigger Point in that specific caller to activate the breakpoint only if the method is called from this caller.